# Can somebody please draw me a pic on how xdelta work in landscape mode?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I want to use translate animation to implement a menu, but I got totally lost at the xxx% thing. I want to use percentile because I want the app to work on devices with all sorts of resolution.

The problem is I can't seem to figure out what percentage corresponds to what screen position.

For example, it appears that 200% is still on screen, -50% isn't off screen?

Is there a set of unifying specs or it depends on how OEMs port the android kernel to their device? For example Nexus device's 50% is different from Samsung's 50%???

Here is the problematic animation code:

```
<set
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
android:fillAfter="true">

<translate
    android:fromXDelta="200%"
    android:toXDelta="160%"
    android:duration="5000" />
</set>
```

Edit:

To make the matter worse, the whole thing seem to be connected with "constraintLayoutParams.leftMargin". It seems that whenever I adject constraintLayoutParams.leftMargin, the percentage (xx%) change, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**From** 
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html

*A vertical and/or horizontal motion. Supports the following attributes in any of the following three formats: values from -100 to 100 ending with "%", indicating a percentage relative to itself; values from -100 to 100 ending in "%p", indicating a percentage relative to its parent; a float value with no suffix, indicating an absolute value.*

```
visit the link for more details.
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for a completely unrelated question (but actually related for me) : how do you place a view squarely on the right hand side of the parent view, with the view's left edge bordering the parent's right edge? I tried "android:layout_marginLeft="100%p" with the underlying logic being "I'm on the 100% of the parent side, which is the rightmost place" but apparently %p here isn't a valid input?

Comment: Yeah! it is completely unrelated so don't use above code. And please show some image snap to understand clearly.

Comment: I kinda figured it out... thank your for your answer! I chose it to be the right oen.